# Python reading the file named by the date of the day?

Tags: python, date, time, request, readfile

There will be more than one `txt` file in the directory named `data`. But I just want to `read` the file that has the `date of that day as the name`. How can I do this ?.

My code:

```
import time

from requests import get

url = "https://zonefiles.io/a/yourApiKey/update/1/"

def domains_ind_day():
    with open('../data/{}.txt'.format(time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y', time.gmtime())), 'wb') as file:
        response = get(url)
        file.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  filename = '../data/' + format(time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y', time.gmtime()) + '.txt'
  with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
```